# gcc compiler cant find external library

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse, gcc, boost

I'm having a question about the Boost library. I compiled it and i can use the library in a project. Now i made a new project and wanted to include . I added the library in the linker and in the C++ compiler. I'm using Eclipse

This is my compiler output:

```
18:45:16 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Asterretje ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o Asterretje.exe main.o Vertex.o RouteCalculator.o Reader.o Graph.o Edge.o -llibboost_regex-mgw48-mt-1_55 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibboost_regex-mgw48-mt-1_55
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

18:45:17 Build Finished (took 915ms)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does it need a `.lib` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Add switch `-L<dir>`, where `<dir>` is directory of boost libraries. And you should cut first 'lib' part from library file name, for example for libmylib.so you should pass -lmylib

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help

I've found the problem. I forgot to insert the searchpath.